# Python - Possible to force raise exceptions regardless try/except blocks?

Tags: python, exception

In Python is there any language (or interpreter) feature to force the python interpreter to always raise exceptions even if the exception offending code is inside a try/except block ?

I've just inherited a larger and old codebase written in python, whose purpose is to communicate with some custom designed hardware we also developed. 
Many communication errors and timeouts are being masked/missed due to the following (simplified) pattern of code:

```
try:
    serialport.write(MSG)
except:
    some_logging_function_mostly_not_working_that_might_be_here_or_not()
    #or just:
    #pass
```

In order to avoid the typical scenario of "just rewrite the whole thing from scratch", I'm currently trying to fix all exceptions errors/timeouts. I'm doing this by disabling by hand the all exception handling code, one at a time.

Comment: I can't speak to python, since I've never used it (hence why I answer as a comment instead of a real answer), but most debuggers have an option to "break on all exceptions".  This may also be called "first-chance exceptions".  It would allow your code to remain unchanged, but treats every "throw" like a breakpoint.  Check to see if your debugger has that feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "all-exceptions" `except:` block is a remarkably bad thing and must simply be found and replaced with sensible except handling.

In this case `grep` is your friend.  A good IDE can help make these unpleasant chores manageable.

But there's no "ignore the code as written" option in Python.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really.  Your best bet is to change the code to something more like this:

```
try:
    serialport.write(MSG)
except:
    some_logging_function_mostly_not_working_that_might_be_here_or_not()
    raise
```

This will make it re-raise the exact exception.  The main thing that you need to understand is that if there were a way to make all exceptions exit the system, you wouldn't be able to use a for loop (iterators raise a StopIteration exception).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to ignore except especially when you are debugging and apply it otherwise.

One good way is to have a global variable say debug=True and conditionally invoke raise:

```
debug=True

def foo:
   try:
       # do some code
   except:
       if debug: raise #put this in all excepts
```

Now set debug to False whenever raise is to muted all across

Answer (score -2):

You can use multiple exception handlers to handle multiple exceptions.

```
try:
    serialport.write(MSG)
except Handler1:
    some_logging_function_mostly_not_working_that_might_be_here_or_not()
    #or just:
    #pass
except Handler2:
    some_logging_function_mostly_not_working_that_might_be_here_or_not2()
    #or just:
    #pass
```